# Display box showing twice C#

Tags: c#, textbox, messagebox

I am performing a validation for my ID field when the user chooses what format it will be. The validation works except for the fact that when it displays the messagebox you select OK, then it repeats once more before going back to the form. I have supplied my code for it below. I used the dialogresult part to see if making it perform an action would stop the problem. This was fixed by using the Click event as mentioned by one of the answers.

```
private void rChkBoxB_ToggleStateChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.StateChangedEventArgs args)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256)
    {
        DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("B does not support numbering over a number!", "Error", 
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            rChkBoxB.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

The new problem is turning the checkbox back to false after the click event. Here is my updated code. The typical checkbox.checked = false does not change it back to false. I used breakpoint to verify I am getting the to the if statement and the value says false for my checkbox. How can I change the property back to false?

```
private void rChkBoxB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256)
    {
        DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("B does not support numbering over a number!", "Error",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            rChkBoxB.Checked = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my guess is `rChkBoxB_ToggleStateChanged` gets called twice. Breakpoint it and check it out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you've set Checked = false in return of the dialogresult?  Hence, toggling the state again?

EDIT: Of note, you are probably using the CheckStateChanged event.  So, you check the checkbox (setting it to true), it fires, you show the MessageBox, you set the checkbox back to false, which in turn, causes the event to fire again (you are changing the state).

This is where you could use the Click event, as opposed to setting a flag (proposed solution).  That way when you set the checkbox back to false, in code, the Click event won't fire.  At runtime, a Click event, for a checkbox, will always toggle the checkbox on/off, no matter where you click on the checkbox.

In conclusion, just use the Click event:

```
    private void rChkBoxB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("B does not support numbering over a number!", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                rChkBoxB.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Of course, in either version of your code, I'm assuming you want to actually check if Text > 256 when you are checking it to true.  So you might want to:

```
    private void rChkBoxB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (rChkBoxB.Checked == false) return; // NEW CODE HERE

        if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256)
        {
            DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("B does not support numbering over a number!", "Error",
                MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                rChkBoxB.Checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I set that way because it is required for that field to be correct because the format can't handle it. Therefore leaving it there would allow it to right to the database.

Comment: Yes, so you need to handle the situation where you toggle it back.

Comment: That rids me of the double notification but it does not change the checkbox to false. I am updating  my post for new code.

Comment: Edit is up for you to review.

Comment: Hey Kpt. Khaos - are you sure about the checkbox not being set to false?  After the MessageBox is displayed, and then OK'd, the checkBox is set back to false (and the Click event doesn't fire again).  That should work.  I just tested it now.

Comment: JustLooking yes it works but the checkbox stays checked after it executes.

Comment: Are you sure?  My testing says otherwise.  If you fail the test (a number greater than 256), you present a MessageBox correct?  Then, after the MessageBox is OK'd, the code sets the checkbox back to false.  When I look at my form (I did a quick test using WinForms), the state of the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: Yeah let me post screen shot

Comment: The screen shots are up.

Comment: Hrmm, this doesn't make sense.  If I set the checkbox to false (in the click event), it does get reflected in the GUI.  Is this a WinForms project or WPF or .. ?  I used WinForms, maybe there is something different with WPF.  I don't think that should matter though.  As I think about it more, there's probably some other event you have wired that's setting it back to true?  Un-wire all your events, and only leave the Click event, I bet it works.  Or just put a breakpoint on any place in code you set the checkbox Checked value.

Comment: It is WinForms project. There is only one other place but I just run an if statement there and it doesn't change the state of the checkbox. That is also triggered off a button event so it has no effect on it. Yeah this is strange.

Comment: There has to be some missing information.  For example, do this right now: Start a brand new WinForms project.  On Form1, drop a checkbox.  Wire up the Click event.  Put this one line of code in the click event: checkbox1.Checked = false; ... I guarantee that every time you click the checkbox, it remains un-checked.  That's basically the same code as what we have displayed (minus the test for > 256 and the MessageBox).

Comment: I know it works I did it take make sure. My validating if statements work but if I try to include that in my validating statements it starts that again and it's not even in the click event.

Comment: If I have the if(checkbox.checked == false) return part. It returns every time even if clicked. It's almost as if the false and true are switched.

Comment: I kid you not if after the dialog.Ok if statement when I set it checkbox.checked = true instead of false the checkbox is false.

Answer (score 2):

The code is not the problem, but the event ToggleStateChanged being called more than one time when `rChkBoxB.Checked = false;`

Comment: Do you think you could look at my edit to see if you know how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** `ToggleStateChanged` event will be fired whenever `Checkbox` state is being changed. Your checkbox state is getting changed when you set `rChkBoxB.Checked = false;` that is the reason why your `ToggleStateChanged` event is invoking twice.

**Solution:**  Take a `bool` variable and make it true when user selects ok , then even if the `ToggleStateChanged` event triggers it wont invoke the function twice as isValid is set to true.

```
bool isValid=false;//declare as class variable

private void rChkBoxB_ToggleStateChanged(object sender, Telerik.WinControls.UI.StateChangedEventArgs args)
{
   if(!isValid)
   {
      if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256)
      {
         DialogResult dialogresult = MessageBox.Show("B does not support numbering over a number!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
         if (dialogresult == DialogResult.OK)
         {
            rChkBoxB.Checked = false;
            isValid=true;
         }
         else
         {
            isValid=false;
         }
      }
   }
   else
   {
      isValid=false;
   }
}
```

Comment: Give me a second to try this but I think you may have something here.

Comment: check my edit now you need to add onmore else block to set isvalid to false

Comment: Do you think you could look at my edit to see if you know how to resolve this issue.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos : are you sure that it is entering if condition and displaying messagebox?

Comment: Yes I used breakpoint and it gets that the value is false. It just never sets the checkbox.

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos: so now your problem is : checkbox is always checked(i mean true) it never sets to false(unchecked) even though you click on OK on `MessageBox`?

Comment: @Kpt.Khaos: so when your checkbox would be checked imean set to true?

Comment: Yes after the click event I use the = false to set the checkbox to unchecked and it never performs the action.

Answer (score 0):

It run two times because you change the checked property inside the radio button. When you change it the CIL see that it generate a new flag and it does again the event.

For anticipating this you can put a second control in the first if

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(rTxtBoxFormatID.Text) > 256 && rChkBoxB.Checked)
{
  ///TODO
}
```

I also suggest to check if the input is correct: in this case you want only int so you can use `int.TryParse(string, out int)` (see reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) or you can use Regex (references [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))